# RX: Buffer TextInput events from Key "LeftShift+OemPlus" to Key "LeftShift+OemPlus"

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Using: .NET 4.6, c#, WPF, ReactiveExtension 2.2.5

My Barcode-Scanner transmits a start and end character (Code39, this is the * character). The key when using the PreviewKeyUp-Event is "LeftShift+OemPlus". I try to use the ReactiveExtensions but don't know exactly how to get the two keys. This is my code so far:

```
IObservable<EventPattern<KeyEventArgs>> keyDown = 
                Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(this, "PreviewKeyDown");
IObservable<EventPattern<TextCompositionEventArgs>> textInput = 
                Observable.FromEventPattern<TextCompositionEventArgs>(this, "PreviewTextInput");
var textInputBuffer = textInput.Buffer(() => 
                    keyDown.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.EventArgs.Key == Key.OemPlus));
```

Now I can subscribe to "textInputBuffer", but this is only half way done. I want the Buffer to begin when key "LeftShift" and directly after that key "OemPlus" is hit, and end with the same sequence of keys. Any idea somebody?

Answer (score 0):

This might get you up and running.

```
var keyDown = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(this, "PreviewKeyDown");
var textInput = Observable.FromEventPattern<TextCompositionEventArgs>(this, "PreviewTextInput");

//Listen to pairs of events
var boundaryEvent = keyDown.Buffer(2,1)
    //Only yeild the pair of events if the pair is LeftShift and OemPlus
    .Where(buffer => 
        buffer[0].EventArgs.Key == Key.LeftShift 
        && buffer[1].EventArgs.Key == Key.OemPlus);


var query = from start in boundaryEvent
            from text in textInput.Buffer(()=>boundaryEvent)
            select text;
//Or
//var query = boundaryEvent.SelectMany(_=>textInput.Buffer(()=>boundaryEvent));
```

**UPDATE**

Here is an updated sample that is a provable/repeatable unit test. Hopefully you can see the mods required to get it right

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Reactive.Testing;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace StackOverflow.Q36340516_BufferedByBoundary
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class BufferByBoundary : ReactiveTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Should_yield_only_text_between_KeyPress_Boundary_events()
        {
            var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
            var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<string>();
            //var keyDown = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(this, "PreviewKeyDown");
            //var boundaryEvent = keyDown.Buffer(2, 1)
            //    //Only yield the pair of events if the pair is LeftShift and OemPlus
            //    .Where(buffer =>
            //        buffer[0].EventArgs.Key == Key.LeftShift
            //        && buffer[1].EventArgs.Key == Key.OemPlus)
            //    .Select(_=>Unit.Default);
            var boundaryEvent = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
                OnNext(0150, Unit.Default), //open
                OnNext(0350, Unit.Default), //close
                OnNext(0550, Unit.Default), //open
                OnNext(0850, Unit.Default)); //close

            //var textInput = Observable.FromEventPattern<TextCompositionEventArgs>(this, "PreviewTextInput")
            //      .Select(evt=>evt.EventArgs.Text);
            var textInput = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
                OnNext(00100, "A"),     //before 1st open
                OnNext(00200, "B"),     //buffer 1
                OnNext(00300, "C"),     //buffer 1
                OnNext(00400, "D"),
                OnNext(00500, "E"),
                OnNext(00600, "F"),     //buffer 2
                OnNext(00700, "G"),     //buffer 2
                OnNext(00800, "H")      //buffer 2
                );

            var query = from start in boundaryEvent.Take(1)
                        from text in textInput.Buffer(() => boundaryEvent)
                        select string.Join(string.Empty, text);

            query.Take(1).Repeat().Subscribe(observer);

            scheduler.Start();

            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[]
            {
                OnNext(350, "BC"),
                OnNext(850, "FGH"),
            },
            observer.Messages);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The skip 1 in `keyDown.Buffer` is to accout for the closing selector in `textInput.Buffer` ?

Comment: No, `Buffer(2,1)` is a pattern used to get overlapping pairs from the same sequence. Other ways of doing it are to Publish().RefCount() then `shared.Zip(shared.Skip(1), (a,b)=>Tuple.Create)` or use `Scan` but `Buffer(2,1)` is a lot less faffing around.

Comment: Well, this is very close, but... First time I enter "*aaa*" I get something like "*aaa". After that I enter "*" and I get "**", then enter "bbb*" and I get "*bbb*bbb*bbb", then five times "*ccc", seven times "*ddd" and so on. There must be a way to clear the buffer between.

Comment: Hmmm, there is some problem with the editor since two "*" means **bold** or italic or whatever. Don't know how to enter two * * ?